# How can I save data in a Cosmos DB with a post request?

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure-cosmosdb

I am currently in the process of creating a microservice and want to save data to my Cosmos DB database with a post request. Unfortunately I have not found anything suitable on the Internet. The connection to the Cosmos DB works and I can call up my get request data from the database.
Does anyone have a solution how the post request can work?

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;

import java.util.Random;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;




@RestController
public class UserResource {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repository;



    @GetMapping("/users")
    public Flux<User> retrieveAllUsers()
    {
        return repository.findAll();
    }
    @GetMapping("/users/{name}")
    public Flux<sendmessage.user.User> retrieveUser(@PathVariable String name)
    {
        Flux<sendmessage.user.User> user = repository.findByName(name);

        return user;
    }
    @PostMapping("/users")
    public String createUser (@RequestBody User user)
    {

        ???;


    }

}
```

```
# ===============================
# DATABASE
# ===============================

# Specify the DNS URI of your Azure Cosmos DB.
azure.cosmosdb.uri=...............

# Specify the access key for your database.
azure.cosmosdb.key=.......................
# Specify the name of your database.
azure.cosmosdb.database=.............

server.port=8800
```

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-cosmosdb-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-documentdb</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Second try

```
public class InsertDefaultValue 
{

        public static void insertUser(String active, String name, String password, String roles, String username)  {

            try
            {


                ConnectionPolicy connectionPolicy = new ConnectionPolicy();
                connectionPolicy.connectionMode(ConnectionMode.DIRECT);
                CosmosClient client = new CosmosClientBuilder()
                         .endpoint("...../")
                         .key("...")
                         .connectionPolicy(connectionPolicy)
                         .consistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.EVENTUAL)
                         .build();




              client.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
              System.err.println("Got an exception!");
              System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }
          }
}
```

````
    public String createUser (@RequestBody User user)
    {
        String password ="hallo"; //generatePassword(10);
        String username=generatePassword(16);
        InsertDefaultValue.insertUser("1",user.getName(),password,user.getRoles(),username);

        return "ok";


    }```
````

Comment: Have you seen this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-sql-api-java?tabs=sync?

Comment: Yes I did. 
ICh habe dafür eine separate Class erstellt und versucht eine Verbindung zu erstellen. CreateItem funktioniert aber nicht so richtig 
133/5000
I created a separate class for this and tried to create a connection. However, CreateItem doesn't really work

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking what parameters you need to pass for http headers, you can check my post about how Cosmos DB REST API works with examples. I used POSTMAN for the examples.
I hope that helps.
https://h-savran.blogspot.com/2019/02/cosmos-db-rest-api-with-postman.html

Comment: Along with of posting link to your blog, please share the relevant code here as well. Also, the question is about creating a CosmosDB document with Java. I am not sure how your answer is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my sample spring WebFlux web app.

https://github.com/RaviTella/SpringBootWebFluxCosmosSQL

Following are the code snippets for saving to a database:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Mono<String> addToReadingList(Book book) {
    book.setReader("Tella");
    book.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    logger.info("Adding a book -> " + book);
    return cosmosRepository
            .createBook(book)
            .map(b -> {
                return "redirect:/readingList";
            });
}

public Mono<Book> createBook(Book book) {
       return container
               .createItem(book)
               .map(CosmosAsyncItemResponse::getItem);
}
```